# Type '(isOpen: boolean) => void' is not assignable to type 'boolean'. Error when using Modal in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm building a custom modal component in my App. But I get this error when Ts typechecking. Here is my code:

Modal.tsx

```
import React, {useEffect, useRef} from 'react';
import {createPortal} from 'react-dom';

import {useOnClickOutside} from "../hooks";

interface Props {
    isOpen: boolean;
    toggle: (isOpen: boolean) => void;
    title: string;
    width?: any;
}

const modalRoot = document.getElementById('modal');

const Modal: React.FC<Props> = ({isOpen, toggle, title, width = 700, children}) => {
    const ref = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
    const el = document.createElement('div');

    useOnClickOutside(ref, () => toggle(false));

    useEffect(() => {
        if (modalRoot) modalRoot.appendChild(el);


        return (() => {
            if (modalRoot) modalRoot.removeChild(el);
        })
    });

    return (
        isOpen ? createPortal(
            <React.Fragment>
                  {children}
            </React.Fragment>, el
        ) : null
    )
};

export default Modal;
```

useModal.tsx

```
const useModal = () => {
    const [isOpen, setIsShowing] = useState<boolean>(false);
    const toggle = (isOpen: boolean) => {
        setIsShowing(isOpen);
    };
    return [
        isOpen,
        toggle,
    ]
};

export default useModal;
```

Using

```
const [isOpen, toggle] = useModal();
return (
   <Modal title={'Enter link URL'}
               isOpen={isOpen} toggle={toggle}> //this line I get error
        <div>....</div>
   </Modal>
)
```

I don't know why. Please help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like typescript is inferring the return type of your `useModal` function to be `(boolean | ((isOpen: boolean) => void))[]`. This causes an issue when trying to assign its first element to `isOpen` because it expects a boolean but you are giving it a `boolean | ((isOpen: boolean) => void)`.

The return type you actually want is `[boolean, (isOpen: boolean) => void]`, so please try explicitly indicating that:

```
const useModal = () : [boolean, (isOpen: boolean) => void]  => {
    const isOpen = true;
    const toggle = (isOpen: boolean) => {
        //setIsShowing(isOpen);
    };
    return [
        isOpen,
        toggle,
    ]
};

export default useModal;
```